# Automatically switch between different web pages

Tags: ubuntu, webpage

I have a large LCD mounted on my wall at my work, and I would like to display some webpage with statistics on it, in a rotating manner - switch to a different webpage every few seconds.

I think that I can run a script to execute and kill the browser with a different webpage every few seconds, but it seems like a very inefficient process. Another idea was to switch the workspaces and keep every browser in a different one, but I don't know how to do that.

Do you know of any way of doing this under Ubuntu?

Comment: I can't provide an answer, but if you are willing to drive that screen by a Windows or Mac machine, you could use our product https://Screensaver.Ninja.

Comment: @Pablo thanks, but this is clearly an Ubuntu question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest solution here is to use one of the Firefox add-ons to switch between tabs in a timed manner. Here are links to couple of them. We use this kind of solution at work and it works like a charm.

- [Tab Slideshow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2688)
- [Auto Toggle Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2668)

Answer (score 2):

Are they webpages that you've created to be used solely for this purpose? Could you use a html redirect to load the next page in sequence after a set time delay?

```
<meta name="refresh" content="10;nextpage.html">
```

Comment: +1 for a very creative answer! I'll check it out (it's my work place).

Comment: I can't touch the source code of the web page - I'll use the extension. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention a specific browser so, with Chrome, the extension Revolver seems fine https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revolver-tabs/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vue Pilot to do this, you can also manage your screens and URL rotations from a central dashboard which is pretty handy. It's compatible with Linux, Mac and Windows so you can use any old machine.

Check it out **https://www.vuepilot.com/**

We use this at our office to cycle through a few dozen dashboard pages, works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use marquee also. Firstly convert the web pages to images by PrtScn and then use them in marquee. I think that will be quick and efficient too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you dont want 100 tabs open this chrome plugin seems like a better 'plugin' solution.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-slideshow/pdblffiahfjjldpkngdpaegghhamefam?hl=en

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.